# Bindings in IIS7 when creating a subdomain

Tags: iis-7, ip, subdomain

I have a domain `www.foo.com` purchase with NameCheap.

I pointed that domain name to my VPS's static IP address and created a web application in IIS7 and it's working correctly.

Now I created another separate web application and set it's binding to `forums.foo.com`.

However the browsers doesn't enter the site and it seems the binding isn't doing quite what I expect it to do.

In Firefox, I get:

> Server not found
>
> Firefox can't find the server at forums.foo.com.

Is there some sort of special configuration I have to do in order for the subdomain to correctly point to my folder in `inetpub`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you have to configure the subdomain with namecheap first?
Who is serving dns for the subdomain?